# Make transition between 2 header logos

Tags: javascript, css

I am having 2 different logos in the header and i applied this function for them to replace each other at certain point.

Hovewer i want to apply some fade in and fade out to them when they make transition. Is this possible only with JS or CSS is included?

```js
$(function () { 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
            $('.logo-image.logo-light img').addClass('active')
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 500) { 
            $('.logo-image.logo-light img').removeClass('active')
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.logo-image.logo-light{
    background:center center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-image: url('http://www.plaforma.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-zastavica.png');
}

.logo-image.logo-light img{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.logo-image.logo-light img.active{
    opacity:1;
}
```

This is the result - i want second logo to be first one which is by default first but now appears as second one when transitioned. Also the logo does not completely disappear, first time doing transitions so for sure my mistake somewhere.

Look - http://www.plaforma.me/studio/

Solution - Reversed opacity in order and added background-color to be black so it does not be transparent.

Comment: No, this is not possible using JS alone. You would need two image elements to begin with, positioned on top of each other, so that you can “fade” one into the other by manipulating its opacity, or something like that.

Comment: You do not need to do two ifs... your code also does nothing at 500 pixels :) Use if/else

Comment: Yes you can do it with JS/CSS, here's an example: https://jsbin.com/wilesufogi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you all, will try now this last example on my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might easier to just rethink your HTML Markup and use CSS to do it. All you would need to do is toggle a class.

```js
var logo = document.querySelector('div.bar')
window.setInterval(()=>{
  logo.classList.toggle('other')
}, 5000)
```

```css
div.bar > span.logo
{ 
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}


div.bar > span.logo1 { 
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);
}


div.bar > span.logo2 {
  position: realtive;
  margin-left: -105px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-out;
}

div.bar.other span.logo2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <span class="logo logo1"></span>
  <span class="logo logo2"></span>
  <span>Hello there!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my edit, i tried to do something with toggling classes

Comment: Well your image background is transparent..... so of course whatever is behind it is going to show

Comment: got it, gotta change background of the image then. But why is second image first displaying and not 'PLAFORMA' logo?

Comment: because you probably have the 1 and 0 reversed..... and you can just set background-color: #000 on the image and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jquery's .fadeIn yet?

I've made up some code.
Not sure if this works but i'll be worth a try

Hope this works,

Ramon

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
            $('.logo-image.logo-light img').fadeIn(0);
        }
```